# Understand and apply the treeplot fuction properly

Tags: matlab, tree

I developed a script to solve the travelling salesman problem (TSP) using the branch and bound algorithm in MATLAB. As a result, the script visualizes a map with the shortest travelling way.

Now I would also like to apply the `treeplot` function to generate a tree to present the result. Unfortunately, I don't know how this function works. When I have 5 cities then I expect 4 further branches after my first node (initial city). After my second node, I expect 3 further branches and so on.

The number of possible cities decreases with every node because every city can be visited just once.

***Expected Tree:***

[image: Here you can see the expected tree]

How does my `treeplot` function have to look like I want to visualize the way `1 => 2 => 3 => 4 => 5` for example?

I stored the shortest way in an array:

```
wayarray_for_tree =

     1     2     3     4     5     1
```

Now when I apply the `treeplot` function, I receive an error message:

> `treeplot(wayarray_for_tree)`
>       Error using `treelayout` (line 28)
>       Bad vector of parent pointers.
>
> Error in `treeplot` (line 18)
>      `[x,y,h]=treelayout(p);`

Comment: You may want to add `matlab` tag. Also please clarify what's your exact question.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation

Comment: @stefx If you show us how you're calling `treeplot` with some sample data and tell us how this doesn't meet your requirements, it will be easier for us to help you fix your code.

Comment: I tryed to make the question more clear and specific

Comment: Additionally I add a picture